# Reset value only if it contains a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a button where if i press it goes down the entire column (eg B) and where it says "x" replace it by "-" and then follows up the already set conditional formatting. Thanks (new to this kind of programming, already tried couple of things but don't function)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Item = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")

    If (StrComp(Items, "x") = 0) Then
        Items = "-"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Replace()` method of `Range` object:

if you want a *full* match:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Replace what:="x", replacement:="-", lookat:=xlWhole
```

if you want a *partial* match:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Replace what:="x", replacement:="-", lookat:=xlPart
```

Comment: @GuillaumeMille, did you get through it?

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late reply, couldnt upvote as i was new. I did get throught it and tweeked a bit as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code should put you on the correct path:

```
Dim Sh As WorkSheet
Set Sh = Sheet("Sheet1")

Dim R As Integer
For R = 1 To Sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If Sh.Cells(R, 2) = "x" Then Sh.Cells(R, 2) = "-"
Next R
```